# Skobbler Maps. Annotations appear as black squares. Android

Tags: java, android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I'm developing an Android app that shows my different POIs with my custom design.

Usually In most cases everything is fine. But sometimes, about 5% cases there are black squares instead of my POI.

Check the screenshot please:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tlqqczq98w926oi/ss1.jpg

I'm using for this `SKAnnotationView.setView` passing my custom View object with `ImageView`. Image can be set to `ImageView` via `setImageBitmap` in background or via `setImageResource`. I tried different ways. And there is no difference with choice of Bitmaps or Resources. In both cases black square can be shown.

Why it could happen? I don't see anything strange in logcat. No error messages, no warnings.

I'm checked for sure that `SKMapSurfaceView.addAnnotation` method is called from UI thread. Always.

I'm using Skobbler Android SDK 3.0.3.

How can I correct this issue? Or how can I detect the problem that cause this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed with the latest SDK release (3.1).